# StrongLoop: Upload images to Dropbox

Tags: node.js, dropbox, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have implemented Dropbox API as follows:

```
function uploadDataToDropbox(ImageCTX, cb){ 
    console.log(ImageCTX);
    var image_uuid = uuid.v1();     
    dbx.filesUpload({contents: ImageCTX , path: '/images/'+ image_uuid +'.png'})
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        cb(null, response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        cb(error, null);
      });       
}
```

Over here I cannot figure out what should be the 'contents' parameter. The value 'ImageCTX' needs to be buffer or string I know. But how to test it using Postman

```
 post.remoteMethod('postMessage', {
description: 'Post a message',
accepts: [
  {arg: 'Description', type: 'String', description: 'Description', required: true},
  {arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}},
  {arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}},
  {arg: 'Category', type: 'String', description: 'Category', required: true}],
returns: {arg: 'success', root: true},
http: {verb: 'POST', path: '/postMessage'}
 });
```

Comment: Do you know how upload using express?

Comment: @Ebrahim yes I know, I am testing my API using Postman, but when I'm debugging it using Webstorm then I could find any files or file clause in the req part...

Comment: Would you mind show upload remote method code?

Comment: What is source of args `Description` and `Category`? And I'm confusing what is the exact problem you got with postman.

Comment: See I need to add a post with description and category and an image. I have created the API and it is perfectly getting description and category from the Postman but when I try to add form-data i.e. an image file. I cannot receive on my backend API or may be I'm not able to identify in which field I should go for image file as description and category gets filled through postman by assigning values to the description and category key. I just need to get that image on my end so that I could upload it through DROPBOX api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121987/discussion-between-syed-asad-abbas-zaidi-and-ebrahim-pasbani).